# Using QuickBlox video chat in IOS without login or password

Tags: ios, quickblox, videochat

I am integrating QuickBlox in my iOS application. The QuickBlox sample code uses two hard-coded QuickBlox users, filling in a login and password for each.

I do not want to ask my user to login with a QuickBlox login.

Is there any way that my user can have a video chat with another user without having QuickBlox login credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup video chat you should have 2 created users.

As you can see, we need opponent's **user_id** to make a call
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios#Call_user

But, you actually can develop 'hidden login'. 
For example, use some device data to create user's login and password. And do it under UI.
For example, you can use **[UIDevice identifierForVendor]** to uniquely identify your users
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: I did not understand what to do exactly with [UIDevice identifierForVendor] I can get the unique identity for the user then what about passowrd but this user login and password not there in qucikblox account show, will the session get created.? I feel I am not clear about quickblox video chat implementation. please could any one help me on this

In qucikblox they concentrated mostly on code samples, they did not tell how to implement user and video chat dynamically, please can any one guide me

Comment: And also please could you tell me how can I do audio chatting with qucik blox. I believe you have  answer to all of my queries

Comment: Audio Chat guide http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios#1_to_1_AudioChat

Comment: Hi  Igor Khomenko is there any way to hold the call in quick blox

Answer (score 1):

I am now implementing with a the user id using the following code.

```
[QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self];
(void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{

    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBAAuthSessionCreationResult.class]){
        // Success, do something
        QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
        user.login = @"garry4";
        user.password = @"garry5santos2";

        [QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];
    }
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBUUserResult.class]){
        // Success, do something
        QBUUserResult *userResult = (QBUUserResult *)result;
        NSLog(@"New user=%@", userResult.user);
        QBUUser *currentUser = [QBUUser user];
        currentUser.ID = userResult.user.ID; // your current user's ID
        currentUser.login = userResult.user.login;
        currentUser.password=@"garry5santos2";// your current user's password

        // set Chat delegate
        [QBChat instance].delegate = self;

        // login to Chat
        [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",result.errors);
    NSLog(@"%d",result.success);
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: THank you  Igor Khomenko